# Hypermedia Restful API using Link Header and Range

Tags: rest, http, hateoas

I'm trying to develop a RESTful api using the hypertext as an engine of application state principals.

I've settled on using the Link header (RFC5988) for all 'state transitions', it seems natural to place links there, and doesn't make my response types specific on an implementation (eg XML/json/etc all just work).

What I'm struggling with at the moment is the pagination of a collection of resources. In the past I've used the Range header to control this, so the client can send "Range: MyObjects=0-20" and get the first 20 back. It seems natural to want to include a "next" relation to indicate the next 20 items (but maybe it isn't), but I'm unsure how to do it.

Many examples include the range information as part of the URI. eg it would be

`Link: <http://test.com/myitems?start=20&end=40>;rel="next"`

Using the range header would I do something like the following?

`Link: <http://test.com/myitems;rel="next";range="myitems=20-40"`

The concern here is that the link feels non-standard. A client would have to be checking the range header to get the next items.

The other thing is, would I just leave this all as somewhat out-of-band information?. Never showing next/previous ranges (as that sort of depends on what the client is doing), and expect the client to just serialize down what it needs when it needs it?. I can use the "accepts-ranges" link hints in the initial link to the collection to let the client know its 'pageable'

eg something like

```
OPTIONS http://test.com
-> Link:"<http://test.com/myitems";rel="http://test.com/rels/businessconcept";accepts-ranges="myitem""
```

Then the client would go, oh it accepts ranges, I will only pull down the first X, and then go for the next range as necessary (this sort of feels like implicit states though).

I can seem to figure out what is really in the best spirit of HATEOAS here.

Answer (score 1):

The link header spec doesn't do exactly what you want AFAIK. It has no concept of identifying client supplied parameters.  The rel doc's for your link can and should specify how to apply your range implementation.

The link-template header spec https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-nottingham-link-template-00#page-3 does a lot of what you want, but that expired.  This specified how to use https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6570 style templates in headers, and if you want to use headers that the direction i'd suggest.

Personally, although I agree having the links in the header abstracts you from the body's content type, i find the link header to be difficult to develop against as you can't just paste a url in a browser and see links immediately.

Comment: I guess the question is that is supplying it in the rel docs acceptable?. It could be, but if i use this style of paging 'next'/'prev' would never be used. I have used http://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-nottingham-link-hint-00 and could add the range, but then of course a client has to build a request from it. (based on info the server supplies)

Not sure which is the best HATEOAS feely, that or just including the range data as query params. I did really like the concept of using Range/Content-Range as it feels like I'm dealing more with a lazily evaluated stream.